# Maps in livecode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, livecode

I want to display maps in a window of livecode. The maps I am thinking are from google maps. If possile I like to restrict the area that is covered by the map. I am trying this from a long time. Can some one please help me out in this issue.

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: Please, include some code in your question and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Although the question is brief and should include more information, it is entirely clear to me what is being asked and I am positive that my answer (below) covers the question. Therefore I don't understand that this question is put on a hold saying "unclear what you're asking". It could have been put on a hold for another reason, but not because of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can display maps in a browser window in LiveCode. If you want to do this in a desktop environment, use the revBrowser external. If you want to use a mobile environment, use the mobileControlCreate command. You can build your URL by script and load that in a browser, e.g. to show Amsterdam in the top half of a card on a mobile device, use this syntax:

```
put "Amsterdam" into myCity
put "http://maps.google.nl/maps?q=" & myCity into myUrl
mobileControlCreate "browser"
put the result into gBrowserID
mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"url",myUrl
put the rect of this cd into myRect
put round(item 4 of myRect / 2) into item 4 of myRect
mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"rect",myRect
mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"visible","true"
```

or use this do display a browser in rect 32,32,288,288 on a desktop device:

```
put "Amsterdam" into myCity
put "http://maps.google.nl/maps?q=" & myCity into myUrl
put the windowID of this stack into myID
put revBrowserOpen(myID,"") into gBrowserID
revBrowserSet gBrowserID,"rect","32,32,288,288"
revBrowserSet gBrowserID,"url",myUrl
revBrowserSet gBrowserID,"visible",true
```

Note that gBrowserID is a global variable and needs to be declared as such.